# PigLatin : filter data by filename

Tags: apache-pig, tar

I have a `tar.gz` file that look like this :

```
myFile.tar.gz
  |__ a.txt
  |__ b.txt
  |__ c.txt
```

I want to develop pig script that process the 3 sub files each one in different way. I tried to filter by file name like this :

```
S = LOAD '/user/admin/otarie/' USING PigStorage(';','-tagFile'); 
A = FILTER A BY $0 matches 'a.txt';
B = FILTER A BY $0 matches 'b.txt';
C = FILTER A BY $0 matches 'c.txt';
```

But the column `$0` contains `myFile.tar.gz` not the sub files, does there any way to filter data by sub file name without decompressig the `tar.gz` file?

Answer (score 0):

[`PigStorage` doesn't recognize tar files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10189585/364696). It recognizes the gzip compression, but after that, it's just reading the raw data from the tar file, and the file information is just another line for processing (and not even a proper line; there is no terminator, so it will run into the first line from each file).

You can't use tar files with PigStorage the way you're trying to; untar and recompress individually and they should work fine.